# Jquery Mobile on J2ME

Tags: jquery-mobile, java-me

I'm developing J2ME. Is it possible using Jquery Mobile for web app in J2ME?
Reviewed according to [jquery mobile web support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/), unwritten for J2ME.
Thanks Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, there is no way to run JavaScript in a J2ME app.

Answer (score 1):

I found this scriptme project, but have never used it.
http://code.google.com/p/scriptme/

According to the site: "ScriptME is an open-source implementation of EcmaScript based on FESI Project written entirely in Java for the J2ME Platform. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users."

There is also the minijoe, which I also did not use...
http://code.google.com/p/minijoe/

"MiniJoe is a "Minimal Javascript Object Environment" that is based on MIDP. MiniJoe consists of a Javascript compiler and interpreter. Both components are written in Java suitable for CLDC 1.1 devices."